# Detect IE-10-*metro* with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there any way to discern IE-10 *metro* users from IE-10 *desktop* users in Google Analytics? The browser version info only lists version number. Any kind of work-around will be acceptable.

I don't have a Win8 machine (yet), but I've had a report that there are some minor design issues with one of my sites in the metro version of IE-10, and I'm trying to assign a level of urgency to this issue by determining the portion of my audience that is affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no definitive way to check this as the user agent strings don't show the difference at this time and the only way to change that would be for Microsoft to make a change to the user agent string for IE10 Metro.

There are a range of checks you an do such as checking ActiveX support (Metro doesn't support ActiveX but IE10 Desktop can have ActiveX switched off as well), check for full screen (Metro will always be full screen but IE10 can also be set to full screen), or check if it is 64 bit (Metro will always be 64 bit but IE10 Desktop can also be 64 bit).

The point being that no matter what check you make it will still be an educated guess. You will need to make a decision yourself as to if you need to prioritise it or not and if you do then simply install IE10 Metro and use that to check the website on as part of your QA as well as the other browsers you check it on.